# Codeigniter controller, javascript console.log()

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

Is there a (simple) way to echo some variables from a Codeigniter controller to the browser console?

Something like

```
public function my_controller_method() {
   if (testing_out_something) {
      $result = "looks like it works";
      $this->log_to_javascript_console->write($result);
   }
}
```

I saw [this javascript class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html) but it looks like it's more for jQuery, I just want to do something simple for debugging purposes.

I guess another way would be to send it to a view, but I don't want my view to change at the moment, I just want to make sure my data is being sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this links may help you :

http://www.codeforest.net/debugging-php-in-browsers-javascript-console

http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/outputting-php-to-browser-console/

Comment: Looks useful but the Controller doesn't display any HTML, that's the work of the view (that's sent the controller)...will this work the same way?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't know what pr is.

Comment: Emmm that's a Cake method, not a Codeigniter method?